# Magento field has a permanent style="display:none" and missing value "required" in class

Tags: php, html, forms, magento-1.9

I've been trying to figure out how is Magento 1.9 changing attributes for one element (region_id, overriden from original forms) from a custom extension made fro Magento 1.7. The code generated is like this:

```
<div class="field" style="display: none;">
    <label class="" for="billing:region_id"></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select id="billing:region_id" class="" title="State/Province" name="billing[region_id]" defaultvalue="499"></select>
        <!-- a lot of option elements -->
        <input id="billing:region" class="input-text" type="text" style="display:none;" title="State/Province" value="Miranda" name="billing[region]"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `style="display:none;"` in one `div` tag and the lack of a value in the class attribute in the corresponding `label` tag.

I've been following every single tutorial about extensions, adding the field where is supposed to be (besides the fact is already a Magento field), but there's no change at all in the corresponding form.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! this is really embarrising... the solution was in the Admin Panel all the time.

Magento gives the option to choose the country of the states list (and if you want to set that field as required, too). In my case is was setted to United States (which is NOT the country where the store is located).

So, in the Admin Panel, just went to `System > Configuration > General > States Options > State is required for > [Country Name]` and chose the right country, clicked in the `Save Config` button... and that's it!.